# If D₂O (Deuterium Oxide) in large quantities, is exposed to explosive amounts of Neutrons or Protons, can it possibly go Nuclear?

Tags: nuclear, protons, nuclear-chemistry, neutrons

If you exposed large amounts of Protons or Neutrons to Deuterium Oxide, could it possibly explode or implode.

Im basing this off a Chemical Simulation, in which simulated Protons are exposed to simulated D₂O, and a large energetic explosion occurs.

In the other scenario, simulated Neutrons are exposed to simulated D₂O, and an extremely energetic (it can overcome proton energy explosions, meaning it will consume the deuterium faster than the protons could) **implosion** and causes a gravitational wave that sucks all simulated material around it into the core, where it is vaporized and destroyed versus a proton bomb causing matter to explode outwards.

Is any of this even realistic? In one scenario, simulated Deuterium acts like a liquid nuclear fission material, but in real life... its heavy water...

**This is all from a computer simulation, I doubt any of it is realistic, but I've never heard of a Deuterium nuclear reaction, Im just curious**

Comment: What kind of "computer simulation" is this supposed to be? What is "go nuclear"? Temperature, pressure? And that part about a *gravitational wave* is just complete nonsense, sorry. Are you writing a novel? I´m sure it could be funny, but sounds to me like there is no *science* in your fiction.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what program and input parameters were used for such "simulation"?

Comment: I think, the current question offers (too) little detail for a reasonable answer on ChemSE.  Speaking of the later, possibly PhysSE is more suitable for this type of question. ChemSE here _typically_ deals with reactions with atom's electrons, rather than their nuclei.  Thirdly, «nuclear» ... of course you may start with heavy water $\ce{D2O}$ (there equally is $\ce{HDO}$ ...) to convert some of the nuclei into (than radioactive) tritium.  But it is not spectactular efficient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritium#Deuterium).

Comment: Deuterium plus a proton makes 3He, a stable isotope. Deuterium plus a neutron makes tritium which decays by beta emission. Neither will 'go nuclear' whatever that means.

Comment: This question is a typical non-sense, based on nothing else than imagination, and fear of scientific discoveries. But well ! Maybe it is related to the process of fusion of deuterium nuclei in a plasma to produce Helium nucleus at a temperature about one million degrees in the so-called H bomb. Maybe the applicant thinks a deuterium nucleus can be obtained from deuterium oxide. It cannot, of course. And protons or neutrons are no use here. it is a typical delirium.

Comment: @Maurice - sustaining D-D fusion (in, e.g., a Tokamak) requires more like 400-500 million K.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is so poor in terms of science, it is also a question which makes very little sense in my mind as a nuclear worker (nuclear chemist)

Comment: @NuclearChemist Makes sense, I was just curious because it was stated as if it was real.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, atoms are "going nuclear" all the time, forming radioactive isotopes under the influence of high-energy particles in the upper atmosphere.  In perhaps the best-known example, the bombardment of nitrogen with high-energy neutrons may generate [carbon-14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-14), which subsequently enters organic matter before it slowly decays (half-life = 5700 years), providing a basis for dating said organic matter.

Carbon-14 is only one of many similarly generated radioisotopes.  A list of such **cosmogenic nuclides** is found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmogenic_nuclide).

Answer (score 1):

Deuterium is a stable combination of a proton and a neutron, but it could accept and bind a proton, forming helium-3 or a neutron, forming tritium. Neither reaction would be explosive, in the sense of liberating enough energy to cause some other nuclear reaction. You might be able to make a small explosion as the sudden heat boils something very fast.

Now, if you could mash two deuterium atoms together, you would get a very hot helium-4, which 50% of the time ejects a proton to give tritium, and 50% of the time ejects a neutron to give helium-3. The heat liberated is significant (2-3 MeV), but not enough to cause another nuclear reaction. Once in a million times, the product is helium-4 and a very energetic gamma ray (about 24 MeV). The pressure required is enormous.

Some fission reactors use heavy water as a moderator because deuterium slows down neutrons without absorbing them much, so if you think about it, D2O would tend to extinguish a nuclear reaction rather than adding to it.